# How to sum certain values from Grafana-Loki logs?

Tags: grafana-loki

I have this log line:

```
Successfully encrypted 189322 bytes for upload req_id=MediaUpload
Successfully encrypted 189322 bytes for upload req_id=MediaUpload
Successfully encrypted 492346 bytes for upload req_id=MediaUpload
```

There's a way to sum the bytes of the matching query log lines? Per example, by the those logs I would like to have a summed value of `870990` bytes or `0.87099` MB.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can. [Check this out](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C%20pattern%20%60Successfully%20encrypted%20%3Cbyte_size%3E%20bytes%20for%20upload%20req_id%3D%3C_%3E%60&line%5B%5D=Successfully%20encrypted%20189322%20bytes%20for%20upload%20req_id%3DMediaUpload&line%5B%5D=Successfully%20encrypted%20189322%20bytes%20for%20upload%20req_id%3DMediaUpload&line%5B%5D=Successfully%20encrypted%20492346%20bytes%20for%20upload%20req_id%3DMediaUpload).

I've used the pattern parser to extract the bytes as a number out of your log lines.

Then you can run a range query on top of that:

Eg.

```
sum by (app) 
(sum_over_time(
{app="your-app"}
| pattern `Successfully encrypted <byte_size> bytes for upload req_id=<_>`
| unwrap byte_size 
| __error__="" [$__interval]
))
```

you can change `$__interval` based on your needs.